# Lubuntu 17.04 upgrade to 17.10 -> Canon MF6530 can't print

Tags: lubuntu, printing, 17.04, 17.10, canon

- The Cannon driver is the newest one, which is [released](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/imageclass-mf6530) on
  11/09/17. I used `cngplp` to correct print data including B/W.

  After that, the printer works fine for 17.04.
  Everyone was happy.
- After a while, Lubuntu keeps on asking me to upgrade to 17.10 ...  I
  regret my decision.
- Why the printer stops working now?

  When I ask it to print something, it can connect to the printer. But
  it keep on "processing" the print job without actually doing
  anything.
- Can disabling airprint help?
- Please enlighten me with your wisdom before something very bad
  happens to me...

I think I might get killed because of this.

Comment: Ubuntu does LTS: stable releases every 2 yrs; the next is due in April; in between, they innovate and explore; 17.10 had a lot of new things; the 3.4 UFR driver from Canon has been reported to not work with 17.10; Canon hope to release a new driver "early 2018"; so meet your fate with bravery!

Comment: I installed 16.04 LTS. The printer printed once, and then stopped working. Everyone is either pointing a gun to my head or blissfully counting and counting on the ubunbunnies. oh well.

Comment: Fixed by reinstalling the canon driver. don't know long will it stay working. keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: It prints the first 2 pages of a 4 pages document correctly, then two pages as blank page. After that, when I kindly ask it to print the doc again, it refuses. And says the computer is already sending data to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I installed 16.04. Then use synaptics (not apt-get) to install cups.

After that, the printer can print first two pages of a document but not the next two pages. It says sending data to printer.

restarting cups services clears the "sending..." message. But it still doesn't print.

Comment: Choosing 17.04 (which has passed its end of life) seems increasingly acceptable now...